# Should "by" go at the beginning or the end of the question? "By what time is it due?" or "What time is it due by?"

Tags: prepositions, sentence-structure, questions

> You have to submit it by Sunday evening.

Can I make question of this sentence like the following? Which one is more natural?

> 1. By what time do we have to submit it?
> 2. What time do we have to submit it by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sentences are grammatically correct and would be understood by a native English speaker. However the second one "*What time do ...*" sounds more natural to me.

Comment: The first one sounds much too formal for everyday conversation.